# The Storage Access Framework exceptions

Tags: android, exception, filepicker

We are getting some issue in the prod as below and It only observed to a few devices in the prod. I believe we don't need to give any read write or read image permission to access any storage framework. Does anyone know what would be the issue ?

Android 12- Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateExcetion: Only owner is able to interact with pending/trashed item content://media/external_primary_images/Media
Android 10/9 - Non-fatal exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreenNavigationEntry() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val filePickerLauncher = rememberFilePickerLauncher(context) { intent ->
        Toast.makeText(context, "File received!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    HomeScreen(
        fileLauncher = {
             val intent = filePickerIntent()
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            filePickerLauncher.launch( filePickerIntent())
        }
    )

}

@Composable
fun rememberFilePickerLauncher(context: Context, 
    onRememberFilePickerLauncherResult: (intent: Intent?) -> Unit,
): ManagedActivityResultLauncher<Intent, ActivityResult> {
    return rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ activityResult ->
        if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            onRememberFilePickerLauncherResult(activityResult.data, context)
        } else {
            onRememberFilePickerLauncherResult(null)
        }
    }
}

private fun filePickerIntent(): Intent {
    val fileType = "application/pdf"
    val mimeTypes = arrayOf(fileType)
    return Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        .setType("*/*")
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
}

fun onRememberFilePickerLauncherResult(intent: Intent?, context: Context) {
        val uri = intent?.data ?: return
        val flag = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
        contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, flag)
        processUri(uri)
}

trying to access below line and getting crash:(Fatal Exception: java/lang.SecurityException: PErmission Denial: Opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from processRecord(URI) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or relate)


fun processUri(uri: Uri) {
Cursor cursor = contenrResolver.query(uri, null, null, null)
}

All code is written in a single activity.
```

Comment: There is no code that would produce those exceptions.

Comment: You only should go for persistable uri permission if you want to use the uri in a different activity or later.

Comment: Thanks, I was waiting for our prod release and we are still getting simillar kind of exception Fatal Exception: java/lang.SecurityException: PErmission Denial: Opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from processRecord(URI) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

Comment: You still did not post code that could produce such an exception.

Comment: If you use startActivityForResult then there should be an onActivityResult.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my question with the code.

Comment: `trying to access below line` you are not showing where and when you execute that line. Do it in onRememberFilePickerLauncherResult first. Also tell complete content scheme of obtained uri.

Comment: I updated that now with all the code. This doesn't happen to all devices. Only observed Galaxy s21 and Android 13 for now

Comment: Probably, I need to add FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION  with FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION . the URI permission grant can be persisted across device reboots.